# How to pass 2 values with AJAX to compare them with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I want to pass 2 values (#cpassword and #password) with AJAX so I can compare those values to check if they match. I've been trying to do it but it seems that I always get just *'#cpassword'*

This is my cpassword-check.js file:

```
// Validate confirm password while typing

$(document).ready(function()
{    
 $("#cpassword").keyup(function()
 {  
  var cpassword = $(this).val(); 

if (cpassword.length > 0)
{  
$("#resultcpass").html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin loading-icon"></i>');


/*$.post("email-check.php", $("#reg-form").serialize())
.done(function(data){
$("#resultmail").html(data);
});*/

$.ajax({

type : 'POST',
url  : 'cpassword-check.php',
data : {
        $(this).serialize(), 
        $('#password').serialize()
},
success : function(data)
    {
          $("#resultcpass").html(data);
       }
});
return false;

}
else
{
 $("#resultcpass").html('');
}

});


});
```

and.. this is my cpassword-check.php file:

```
  <?php

  $host="localhost";
  $user="root";
  $pass="";
  $dbname="lr";

  $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}",$user,$pass);

  if($_POST['cpassword']) 
  {
  $cpassword = strip_tags($_POST['cpassword']);
  $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

  if ( $cpassword != $password ){

       echo "<i class='fa fa-circle user-validation-w pull-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><span class='availability pull-right'> Must match with password</span>";

   } else  {

  echo "<i class='fa fa-check user-validation-ok pull-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><span class='availability pull-right'></span>";

 }
}
?>
```

I just started learning so please explain it really slow.

Thank you.

Comment: Pass then in an array

Comment: **data : {cpassword: $(this).val(), 
password: $('#password').val()}** try this hope it helps

Comment: @Curiousdev Thanks! That worked!

Comment: @DiegoRios completely my pleasure **Merry Christmas** :-)

Comment: @Curiousdev Merry Christmas to you too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use property name in the data object as @Curiousdev said.

Try the following:

```
data : {
  cpassword: $(this).val(),
  password: $('#password').val()
}
```